# Model data not clearing onRouteMatched

Tags: sapui5

I have set up oViewModelData containing blank arrays, which is correctly set to the model on onInit.

However, when I route the page again, rather than refreshing the page, (onRouteMatched), the old data remains from the previous page.

How to clear/refresh oViewModelData onRouteMatched?

```
oViewModelData: {
    siteInfo: {},
    surveyInfo: {},
    categories: []
},

onInit: function() {
    this.getView().setModel(new JSONModel(this.oViewModelData), "view");
},

_onRouteMatched: function(oEvent) {
    this.getView().setModel(new JSONModel(this.oViewModelData), "view");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create kind of template and re-initialize every time from it like following:

```
oViewModelDataTemplate: {
    siteInfo: {},
    surveyInfo: {},
    categories: []
},

_onRouteMatched: function(oEvent) {
    this.oViewModelData = jQuery.extend(true, {}, this.oViewModelDataTemplate);
    this.getView().setModel(new JSONModel(this.oViewModelData), "view");
}
```

... or simply

```
_onRouteMatched: function(oEvent) {
    this.oViewModelData = {
        siteInfo: {},
        surveyInfo: {},
        categories: []
    };
    this.getView().setModel(new JSONModel(this.oViewModelData), "view");
}
```

BTW, A special property for model data is not needed, you always can get it from model.

Comment: I tried the above. The model data itself does now clear. However, the view itself does not seem to refresh because I get a duplicate componentID error when creating the view using the model..... any ideas?

Comment: Probably you create the view for the 2nd time while it's not needed.

Comment: Could you please explain

Comment: Before creating it another time you need to call destroy() on the old instance if you don't want to reuse it. Better use router https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/index.html#/topic/1b6dcd39a6a74f528b27ddb22f15af0d